# Create an account on polygon pos blockchain using python

Tags: blockchain, account, web3py

I want to get the mnemonics to create the phrase key; the private key from the mnemonics and the address.

I tried using web3.py and it was creating a node in Ethereum blockchain which was accessible in the polygon testnet but wanted to do that in polygon itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code connects to the mainnet of the Polygon network. Just replace the URL with the appropriate testnet URL. Once you've connected to the network, use the w3 object to interact with the blockchain.

But i think its easy to Connect trough provider. For all my Work im using GetBlock. You can use the requests library in Python to make HTTP requests to the GetBlock API.
And in any Problem just Ask their support, lol